# Strange error in itemize with menukeys and \lstinline

Tags: listings, itemize, menukeys

A user of my [`menukeys`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) package found a strange error an if don’t have any idea what’s the cause and all the more how to fix it …

The following example make the bullet move to the right inside the text if there is a `\menu` including `\lstinline` right behind `\item`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{menukeys}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Test
    \item \menu{Test \lstinline|test|}
    \item \lstinline|test|
    \item \menu{Test}
    \item \mbox{}\menu{Test \lstinline|test|}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: strange result]

The user found out the an `\mbox` can help but this should’t be the only way to fix this – I hope …

Comment: Supplying `\lstinline` (or any verbatim content) as an argument to a macro is a problem. Look at how the formatting differs from item 3 (correct) and that inside `\menu`. For small inline verbatim content, boxing before passing as an argument is almost always an option.

Comment: The problem disappears if `\leavevmode` is put at the beginning of the definition of `\menu`. This shouldn't be a problem, because the all the "menu" commands are to start a new paragraph.

Comment: Finally fixed in version 1.2, which will be available on CTAN soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LaTeX's `\item` of environment `itemize` delays the setting of its label by using `\everypar`. The label is stored in a box, printed at the start of the paragraph to the left (`\parindent` is `0pt`) and the box is void afterwards.

`\menu` of `menukeys` uses `\tikz`. That stores the contents in a box first and afterwards the box is set. Very simplified:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{...}%
\leavevmode\box0
```

The contents of `\menu`/`\tikz` contains `\lstinline`. It calls `\leavevmode` right at the beginning. This explains, why `\lstinline` right after `\item` works. Inside an `\hbox` `\leavevmode` does not start a paragraph. `\lstinline` calls `\lst@Init`, an excerpt from its definition:

```
\def\lst@Init#1{%
  ...
  \ifhmode\ifinner \lst@boxtrue \fi\fi
  \lst@ifbox
    \lsthk@BoxUnsafe
    \hbox to\z@\bgroup
      $\if t\lst@boxpos \vtop
    \else \if b\lst@boxpos \vbox
    \else \vcenter \fi\fi
    \bgroup \par\noindent
  \else
  ...
}
```

Default for `\lst@boxpos` is `b`, thus `\noindent` starts a paragraph inside a `\vbox`.
At the begin of the paragraph `\everytoks` is executed and the label is set. Afterwards the label box is void (by `\box`, up to the group level of `\item`). This explains the label inside the menu item.

Then the menu item that has been stored in a box is set as entry in the `itemize` environment, correctly using `\leavevmode`. But it is too late now, the label is
already set and is not repeated, the label box is void.

Fix suggestions:

- As egreg already said, `\menu` (and the other similar macros) should call `\leavevmode`
  right at the beginning. Anyway `\menu` will print material that will start a paragraph.

  Manually it can be redefined:

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \newcommand*{\org@menu}{}
  \let\org@menu\menu
  \protected\def\menu{\leavevmode\org@menu}% or
  % \renewcommand*{\menu}{\leavevmode\org@menu}
  \makeatother
  ```
- `\lst@Init` uses the hook `\lsthk@BoxUnsafe` if a vertical box is used.
  `\everypar` can be cleared there:

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \lst@AddToHook{BoxUnsafe}{\everypar{}}%
  \makeatother
  ```

Both ways fix the issue:

> [image: Result]